# CombineLatest with RxView.clicks

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-binding

I am using Rxbinding library for detecting clicks on a textview and textchanges in an editbox. I need to have either a textview clicked or a non-empty editbox and to detect that I am using combinelatest operator on two observables as below:

```
Observable<Void> obsPriceOnReq = RxView.clicks(vPriceOnReq).asObservable();
    obsPriceOnReq.subscribe(new Action1<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Void aVoid) {
            mPriceOnReqBool = !mPriceOnReqBool; // Statement-1
            // Do some work here.
    });


Observable<String> obsBudget = RxTextView.textChanges(vProjectBudget).map(charseqToStr);
    obsBudget.subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(String s) {
            mBudgetFilledBool = checkPosDouble(s); // Statement-2
        }
    });

Observable.combineLatest(obsPriceOnReq, obsBudget, new Func2<Void, String, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(Void aVoid, String s) {
            return mBudgetFilledBool || mPriceOnReqBool; // Statement-3
        }
    }).subscribe(new Action1<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Boolean aBoolean) {
            // Do some work here
        }
    });
```

The issue is whenever I click on *vPriceOnReq*(TextView), **Statement-1** is not called but only **Statement-3** is called. But whenever I enter text in the *vProjectBudget*(EditText), **Statement-2** as well as **Statement-3** are always called. Can someone please help me understand what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

add `.replay(1).refCount()` to the end of `obsPriceOnReq` 
so you'll have:

```
Observable<Void> obsPriceOnReq = RxView.clicks(vPriceOnReq)
    .asObservable()
    .replay(1)
    .refCount();
```

and use `obsPriceOnReq.withLatestFrom(obsBudget, new Func2<>...)` instead of `.combineLatest()` it will make you app react only for clicks and takes the latest item from `obsBudget`. [About click based events in RxJava](https://medium.com/appunite-edu-collection/rxjava-click-based-events-d9eb773381ab#.rqpz3fx3a)